# XML parsing returns 40 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to parse the XML response to an object but it throws exception.

The link of response is [this](http://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?format=xml&venue.city=new%20york&performers.slug=new-york-rangers):

```
<response>
  <meta>
     <per_page>10</per_page>
     <total>20</total>
     <geolocation>None</geolocation>
     <took>8</took>
     <page>1</page>
  </meta>
  <events>
  <event>
   ...
  </event>
  <event>
   ...
  </event> 
  ....
  </events>
</response>
```

**Code**

```
     queryString = queryString.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    try {
        URL page = new URL(queryString);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) page.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

       this.response = (Response) JAXB.unmarshal(in, Response.class);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

**Exception**

```
javax.xml.bind.DataBindingException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 40   
counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "events"
    this problem is related to the following location:
....
```

**Object classes**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
public class Response {
    @XmlElement(name="per_page")
    private int per_page;
    @XmlElement(name="total")
    private int total;
    @XmlElement(name="geolocation")
    private String geolocation;
    @XmlElement(name="took")
    private int took;
    @XmlElement(name="page")
    private int page;
    @XmlElement(name="events")
    private List<Event> events = null;

    **getters and setters**
```

**Objects**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="event")
public class Event {
    @XmlElement(name = "links")
    private String link;
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @XmlElement(name = "stats")
    private Stats stats;
    @XmlElement(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @XmlElement(name = "announce_date")
    private String announce_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "score")
    private float score;
    @XmlElement(name = "date_tbd")
    private boolean date_tbd;
    @XmlElement(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @XmlElement(name = "datetime_local")
    private String datetime_local;
    @XmlElement(name = "visible_until_utc")
    private String visible_util_utc;
    @XmlElement(name = "time_tbd")
    private boolean time_tbd;
    @XmlElement(name = "taxonomies")
    private List<Taxonomie> taxonomies;
    @XmlElement(name = "performers")
    private List<Performer> performers;
    @XmlElement(name = "url")
    private String url;
    @XmlElement(name = "created_at")
    private String created_at;
    @XmlElement(name = "venue")
    private Venue venue;
    @XmlElement(name = "short_title")
    private String short_title;
    @XmlElement(name = "datetime_utc")
    private String datetime_utc;
    @XmlElement(name = "datetime_tbd")
    private boolean datetime_tbd;

    **getters and setters**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JAXB implementations treat public fields and properties as mapped.  When you annotate a non-public field it also becomes mapped.  Then if you have a mapped field an property with the same name you will get this exception.

When you annotate fields you need to annotate your class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

---

**Note:**

You are currently adding more annotations on your model than you need to.  Since JAXB is configuration by exception you only need to add annotations where you want the XML representation to differ from the default.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html